# Image local thresholding

Tags: matlab, image-processing, threshold

I have an image to which I want to apply segmentation using local thresholding. This requires the following steps:

- first segment the image into many sub-images
- implement local thresholding by computing the average within each sub image
- convert the image matrix to binary, by comparing each pixel value with the value of the sub-image local average:

  - if the pixel value is above or equal to the local average, then pixel value = 1
  - if the pixel value is below the local average, then pixel value = 0

My image is unit 8 with 240*320 pixels. How can I implement local thresholding to it using MATLAB? I want to compute the average over each 31*31 sub-image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
n=31;
im2=(im>conv2(im,1/(n^2)*ones(n),'same'))
```

Comment: please , can i understand what do you mean by:                       1/(n^2)*ones(n),

Comment: It's a mean-filter of size n.

Comment: thanks alot but my image still have a problem when i implement the above line , and i don't know how to manipulate it you can see my resultant image here http://www.2shared.com/photo/yiw4w0vf/rori.html

Comment: when i do thinning and skeletonization , the result is not ideal for what i want , the only thing that i want to obtain is the veins in the hand

Comment: What are you talking about? why do you do thinning and skeleton? It's not in your question.

Comment: yes ,before i asked this question i applied thinning and skeleton on this result , but the final result was not good , so i thought that the cause of error is in applying local thresholding in error way , but when i implement your code  , i obtain the same result .